# How to create a transparent Apple Touch icon for Safari bookmarks?

Tags: ios

When browsing through my Safari bookmarks on an iPad, it seems that some of the bookmarks, e.g., the one for Stack Overflow are transparent: there are no visible borders and the background color of the icon is exactly the same as that of the background outside the icon.

See the picture below.

To me it seems that the icon is not just using the same background color, but it is 'transparent'. If you look at the picture, the Stack Overflow has the shadowing effect, but the other icons do not (or am I just imagining?).

What is the trick here? How to make the icon look transparent? Will the transparency turn the background into black - as one could expect based on numerous postings on using transparency for Apple icons?

If this is just a question of using the same color code with the rest of the background, then what color code should I use?

[image]

Comment: What's an Apple Touch icon? Are you referring to a iOS app icon?

Comment: Can you edit the question and add a screenshot showing the Stack Overflow icon with transparency?  I don't see it on mine.

Comment: He's referring to icons of web pages.

Comment: I re-worded the whole question based on your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using:

- A transparent favicon;
- A transparent image that Apple likes to call "Apple Touch icon", which is mainly used as an icon when users add a web page of a website to the Home of their iOS devices.

Comment: Thanks! I was just too confused about these postings about transparency turning the background to black that I did not even try to apply that for my website icons. Transparent icons seem to work there flawlessly (at least on my iPad).

Comment: I tried setting something like this up today, and could not get it to work - iOS fills in the background as black :-(.  Does anyone know if Apple closed this loophole?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.  Quoting Apple:

> Avoid transparency. An app icon should be opaque. If the icon’s boundaries are smaller than the recommended sizes—or you use transparency to create “see-through” areas—the resulting icon can appear to float on a black background, which tends to look especially unattractive on the beautiful wallpapers that users choose.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/AppIcons.html

Comment: This is possible. We are not talking about apps here, but websites.

Comment: From the original question my answer was valid - Safari was not mentioned, 'apple touch icon' was, so I assume the OP was asking about web clip icons.  Now it has been re-worded, agreed, @CeceXX has the solution.